# Comparing two text files using R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two text files and list the differences in any log file, To achieve this I have used "diffr" library with below commands but the comparison results are being shown on R studios viewer console tab. Can anyone help me write better code to compare text files and list the differences?

Also, what should I use if I want to compare files in a loop, as I am having multiple files saved for same query in different environment?

**Code:**

```
library(diffr)

setwd("C:/Users/squraishi/Desktop/OnDemand/R_ExtractDataSnapshot/Results")

prod_file <- read.csv2(file = "F_Query_Prod_7 .txt", header = TRUE, sep = "")
beta_file <- read.csv2(file = "F_Query_Beta_7 .txt", header = TRUE, sep = "")

diffr("F_Query_Prod_7 .txt", "F_Query_Beta_7 .txt", contextSize = 0, minJumpSize = 500)
```

Comment: Well, you're `print()`ing the output. What happens if you assign the output of `diffr()` to a variable (e.g. `results <- diffr("F_Query_PRod…)`) and then examine it?

Comment: Hi Shoaib, it is customary on here to include a minimum reproducible example so people can cut and paste your R code into their own sessions, have it run and see the error you are getting, then propose solution. In this case however you are asking a very broad "how to" question which is generally not acceptable here. You can edit your question to show errors you are getting, and desired output, and then someone can help you. Thanks :)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I tried assigning the output of diffr() to a variavble and printing it. The comparison result is being displayed under Viewer console only.

Comment: Gotcha. So the next question is (since I now know what this package is) why would you expect a package described as _"R package for creating code differences in JavaScript based on codediff.js"_ to actually return output you can use? It's an HTML widget for R and it kinda says it's going to be "in JavaScript" and not a general purpose function.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, Thanks for your comment, Actually I'm completely new to R language and I need to write this comparison code in R only. I could find the diffr() package in google so I've used this. Please suggest a better solution which can compare text files and write the differences in another text files,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That HTML widget package won't give you back output but it's based on a [javascript library](https://github.com/muschellij2/diffr/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/codediff/difflib.js) that was [based](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) on a [python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html).

We'll use the Python version but we *won't* use the `reticulate` package b/c I'm not about to show how to iterate over Python structures in R, so we'll take the pointer from the Python page about the script being at `Tools/scripts/diff.py` and grab it from [github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/scripts/diff.py) to avoid trying to find it on your system. This *does* mean python needs to be installed. Python 3 to be precise (since that's a fragile, fragmented ecosystem).

```
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".py")
on.exit(unlink(tf), add = TRUE)
writeLines(
  readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/Tools/scripts/diff.py"),
  tf
)
```

Now, we'll find the `python3` binary on your system and the `pip3` binary on your system:

```
python <- Sys.which("python3")
pip <- Sys.which("pip3")
```

And make sure a really critical module is installed that should always be installed but python is so daft it isn't:

```
# just in case you don't have it
system2(command = pip, args = c("install", "datetime"))
```

Now run the diff on two made up files of mine:

```
system2(
  command = python, 
  args = c(
    tf, 
    path.expand("~/Data/so.txt"), 
    path.expand("~/Data/so1.txt")
  ),
  stdout = TRUE
) -> res
```

And see the output you now need to parse:

```
res
##  [1] "*** /Users/bob/Data/so.txt\t2018-10-15T06:38:07.169832-04:00" 
##  [2] "--- /Users/bob/Data/so1.txt\t2018-10-18T08:50:51.745551-04:00"
##  [3] "***************"                                              
##  [4] "*** 6,29 ****"                                                
##  [5] "  QX = X-ray|NRW"                                             
##  [6] "  UI = Q000000981"                                            
##  [7] "  "                                                           
##  [8] "- *NEWRECORD"                                                 
##  [9] "- RECTYPE = Q"                                                
## [10] "- SH = analogs & derivatives"                                 
## [11] "- QE = ANALOGS"                                               
## [12] "- QA = AA"                                                    
## [13] "- QT = 1"                                                     
## [14] "- "                                                           
## [15] "- *NEWRECORD"                                                 
## [16] "- RECTYPE = Q"                                                
## [17] "- SH = abnormalities"                                         
## [18] "- QE = ABNORM"                                                
## [19] "- QX = agenesis|NRW"                                          
## [20] "- QX = anomalies|EQV"                                         
## [21] "- QX = aplasia|NRW"                                           
## [22] "- QX = atresia|NRW"                                           
## [23] "- QX = birth defects|NRW"                                     
## [24] "- QX = congenital defects|NRW"                                
## [25] "- QX = defects|NRW"                                           
## [26] "- QX = deformities|NRW"                                       
## [27] "- QX = hypoplasia|NRW"                                        
## [28] "- UI = Q000002"                                               
## [29] "--- 6,8 ----"
```

Having done all that ^^, you could also just use `tools::Rdiff()`:

```
(res <- tools::Rdiff("~/Data/so.txt", "~/Data/so1.txt", Log=TRUE))
## $status
## [1] 1
## 
## $out
##  [1] "files differ in number of lines" "9,29d8"                         
##  [3] "< *NEWRECORD"                    "< RECTYPE = Q"                  
##  [5] "< SH = analogs & derivatives"    "< QE = ANALOGS"                 
##  [7] "< QA = AA"                       "< QT = 1"                       
##  [9] "< "                              "< *NEWRECORD"                   
## [11] "< RECTYPE = Q"                   "< SH = abnormalities"           
## [13] "< QE = ABNORM"                   "< QX = agenesis|NRW"            
## [15] "< QX = anomalies|EQV"            "< QX = aplasia|NRW"             
## [17] "< QX = atresia|NRW"              "< QX = birth defects|NRW"       
## [19] "< QX = congenital defects|NRW"   "< QX = defects|NRW"             
## [21] "< QX = deformities|NRW"          "< QX = hypoplasia|NRW"          
## [23] "< UI = Q000002"
```

but I wanted to show the twisty path first :-)

Comment: Thanks!
tools::Rdiff()
This is working for me and I'm able to save the difference in log files.